# How to hide reference images in different orthographics?

Tags: 3d-view, image, orthographic

I have two background images, one for viewing at the front and one for viewing at the side.

I've changed some of the image settings so that you can only see them in orthographic view but the problem with that is when I am viewing the model from the front I can see the black outline from the side image Empty object cutting down the middle (you can see I have these lines highlighted orange in the below images)

Is there a way to hide these when viewing from the other angle? It's a bit tedious to manually hide/unhide the image when I switch views.

[image: Front view with side view image highlighted]
[image]

Comment: you could simply move them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move images from center at 1m or what offset would you prefer X and Y axis it's would't be harm for modeling process.Hope it will help you.
Also make separate scene collection and move all references to there as you do so turn on in filter outliner tab with arrow and then next to collection unpin arrow (or next to each image).It will protect you from accidentally move image while modeling.
Sorry for bad English.  [image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, especially for the seperate scene collection tip. Don't worry, your English is good.